# marginaleffects always giving the same estimates for a reference category when using two contrasts (R)

Tags: r, interaction, r-marginaleffects

I am trying to calculate marginal effects of a triple interaction using the `marginaleffects` package in r. My regression looks like the following:

```
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)

fmla <-  as.formula(paste0("DV ~ ",k,"*var1:(var2 + control)  + var2 + control | FE"))

reg <- feols(fmla, data = test_df , vcov="cluster")

plot_cme(congress_reg,variables = c("var2"), condition = list("var1",k), draw = FALSE)
```

Where `k` is a set of multiple dummy variables (this function is run in lapply) `var1` is a dummy variable and `var2` is a factor variable with 5 levels, where the reference level (0) is specified correcly. `var1` is interacted without estimating a base effect, because it is completely dependent on `var2`.

My problem is that when I run this, I want to estimate the contrast for both var1 and k. But every time I run this, I get variation for the marginal effects of var2 by k when `var1` = 1, however when `var1` = 0, the estimates are identical, regardless of the level of `k`. I have tried this for different inputs into `k`. The point estimates may be different in the different levels of `var1` and so are the confidence intervals, but within each `var1` level, when k = 0, the two estimates are identical. My plots drawn (with a bit of tidying after setting `draw = FALSE`) of this look like the following:

[image: plot]

Where the x-axis is `var1`, the facet_wrap is `var2` and the color is `k`. I know that these are not accurate, because there is different variation across levels of k in each condition. I also know that there is no missing levels of any of the variables, and no coefficients drop.

Am I misunderstanding how `plot_cme` calculates the slopes? Can multiple contrasts not be specified like this?

**EDIT, Updated with Potential Solution**

After writing this question out and playing with the data some more, I realized that I never specified the baseline effect for `k` in interaction with `var2`, outside of the triple interaction. When I do this, using a formula like the following:

```
library(fixest)
library(marginaleffects)

fmla <-  as.formula(paste0("DV ~ ",k,"*var1:(var2 + control)  +",k,"*var2 + control | FE"))

reg <- feols(fmla, data = test_df , vcov="cluster")

plot_cme(congress_reg,variables = c("var2"), condition = list("var1",k), draw = FALSE)
```

I now do get variation in the estimates, showing the following:

[image: plot2]

So I think this is the reason why the second contrast did not work. There was no *baseline* reference level against which to calculate a marginal effect, so this contrast was fixed.

Is my intuition correct here? Would anyone be able to verify if this was likely the problem, or is there still something I have wrong? (I know this is difficult to say without providing replication data)

Comment: It's impossible to say without replication data, but your intuition sounds plausible at least. Please use `plot_slopes()` instead of `plot_cme()`. The function was renamed a while ago and the old name will eventually be deprecated.

Comment: Okay great, thank you for looking this over. And I will be sure to switch to the new function. Your package is phenomenal!